# How to fix the SQL error message 208 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datatable

This is my first time using SQL Server and I am planning to make a WPF C# application that connects to SQL Server to save users and other data. I was following a Youtube video tutorial but I came up with this problem when trying to test the data within my tables:

[image]

I am trying to display the data within my 'Accounts' table through this query

I have tried looking up the problem and the first thing that came up was that "master" was wrong, I selected msdb instead, however it did not fix the problem

This might be a very simple problem but this is my first time using SQL and databases.

UPDATE: I did

```
DB_NAME()
```

and it came back as 'master'

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to select the database you created. SQL Server creates a few databases of its own where it stores system data. If you want to store your own data, create your own database and select that.

Comment: @John where do I go to select the database I created? And if I haven't made one yet, how would I make one?

Comment: Just to be sure, issue the `SELECT DB_NAME()`  select and show what's the result.

Comment: In this instance, is my database name "Database1" as it says in the server explorer?

Comment: @TomasChabada it came up with a table and had 'master' in it

Comment: try `select * from Database1.Accounts` or `use Database1 GO select * from Accounts`

Comment: @J.Salas it said "Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Database 'Database1' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly."

Answer (score 1):

At the top, in dropdown select your 'database name' instead of 'master database'. I guess Accounts table is in Database1.mdf. Please select Database1.mdf.

Comment: The options in that drop down menu are: master, model, msdb, tempdb

Comment: Okay. Please try in this way then. Select * from Database1.mdf.Accounts

Comment: I have tried them all and the result did not change, I clicked on the properties of "Database1.mdf" and it said the name was "C:\Users\trist\source\repos\Task 3 2022\Database1.mdf"

Comment: It says "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Database1.mdf.Accounts'."

Comment: In the Image, it is showing 'Not Connected' in the explorer. it might be becoz of that. Have you connected to the right server or DB?

Comment: That says I am not connected to Azure. I do not want to use Azure as it is too advanced and complex for what I am trying to achieve in my app I believe. I won't be storing more than 100 pieces of data